# Ubuntu 12.04 not detecting 2nd screen

Tags: unity, drivers, graphics, display, intel-graphics

I have been trying to solve this problem for around 2 months and have seen pretty much every possible solution on this site and everywhere else with no success .

Im running ubuntu 12.04 with intel 4th gen graphics(no dedicated graphics card) . I tried playing around with my graphics drivers and cant remember exactly what I did or in what order but this is the gist of it - I installed the oibaf drivers for ubuntu and installed compiz . The problems seemed to come up before installing compiz .

My system doesnt detect a second monitor(the monitor is fine btw, I'm on a laptop) . when i connect the monitor it simply mirrors the display but at the same resolution as the primary display . I have gone to `System Settings->Displays` and the second monitor doesnt show up. All my 3d unity effects have dissappeared ex. the sidebar now shows icon more 2d like , the alt+tab switcher is now 2d . Also my icons seem a little more blurry so it seems like its a  driver issue

I have tried -

```
unity --reset
```

This made my display go crazy but my 3d unity effects returned but went away as soon as i restarted . The 2nd screen still didnt work

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:glasen/intel-driver
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/x-updates
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-video-intel

sudo apt-get install --reinstall mesa-utils
```

Also I purged the oibaf drivers with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:oibaf/graphics-drivers`
No change

Another thing is that every time after I type my password and hit login after boot, my screen goes gray for about 3 seconds and then displays my desktop.

A lot of the suggestions that I found online tell me to edit my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` file(contents below) , I have a feeling that the issue might be in here somewhere as it has no mention of my intel graphics driver anywhere. Also , in `System Settings -> Details -> Graphics` , I find this :-

Graphics - Gallium 0.4 on llvmpipe (LLVM 0x301)

Experience - Standard

here are the contents of my xorg.conf file :-

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "X.org Configured"
    Screen      0  "Screen0" 0 0
    Screen      1  "Screen1" RightOf "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath   "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/misc"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/cyrillic"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi/:unscaled"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/Type1"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/100dpi"
    FontPath     "/usr/share/fonts/X11/75dpi"
    FontPath     "/var/lib/defoma/x-ttcidfont-conf.d/dirs/TrueType"
    FontPath     "built-ins"
EndSection

Section "Module"
    Load  "dbe"
    Load  "glx"
    Load  "dri"
    Load  "extmod"
    Load  "record"
    Load  "dri2"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Keyboard0"
    Driver      "kbd"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    Identifier  "Mouse0"
    Driver      "mouse"
    Option      "Protocol" "auto"
    Option      "Device" "/dev/input/mice"
    Option      "ZAxisMapping" "4 5 6 7"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor0"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier   "Monitor1"
    VendorName   "Monitor Vendor"
    ModelName    "Monitor Model"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "Rotate"                # <str>
        #Option     "fbdev"                 # <str>
        #Option     "debug"                 # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card0"
    Driver      "fbdev"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
        ### Available Driver options are:-
        ### Values: <i>: integer, <f>: float, <bool>: "True"/"False",
        ### <string>: "String", <freq>: "<f> Hz/kHz/MHz",
        ### <percent>: "<f>%"
        ### [arg]: arg optional
        #Option     "ShadowFB"              # [<bool>]
        #Option     "DefaultRefresh"        # [<bool>]
        #Option     "ModeSetClearScreen"    # [<bool>]
    Identifier  "Card1"
    Driver      "vesa"
    BusID       "PCI:0:2:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "Card0"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen1"
    Device     "Card1"
    Monitor    "Monitor1"
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     1
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     4
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     8
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     15
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     16
    EndSubSection
    SubSection "Display"
        Viewport   0 0
        Depth     24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Answer (score 1):

I feel really stupid as its been like 5min since I posted my question. I solved it! I just deleted my xorg.conf file . All my 3d effects and my monitor started working .I'm guessing that that file got added by one of the packages I installed along the way while playing around. I hope that this helps someone in the future .